# How to align dragged object to origin of drag?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout that has five Views inside, they form a 1x5 grid.

This LinearLayout will be dragged.

I am currently setting setting onTouchListeners on each of five Views, checking which of the five the drag originated from and calling motionEvent.getAction() on the LinearLayout.

This is imperfect, because the LinearLayout is dragged by it's center and not by the point of drag start.

Is there any way to transform the LinearLayout at the start of motionEvent so the View the drag originates from is under the finger while dragging?

MyTouchListener that is set on each of the five Views inside LinearLayout

```
    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    //public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        LinearLayout ship = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
        dragCellIndex = ship.indexOfChild(view);
        dragCellTotal = ship.getChildCount();
        view = ship;

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {            
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you make some attempt? Writed some codes?

Comment: I have added the touch listener I am using to original post. I have tried checking how many cells are in the LinearLayout to the left and right of drag origin and for each on the left setTranslationX(cell.length()*-1) and on the right setTranslationX(cell.length()). That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'd like to make a bit of math calculations. Retrieve the touch of your finger / dragging point X and Y coordinates from the motionEvent, calculate the difference of them with the X and Y coordinates of the top-left corner of your LinearLayout, and save them inside 2 variables.

This way, when you drag the LinearLayout, you simply add these variables to X and Y coordinates and move the LinearLayout to that point. I hope you've got the idea.

I've used this method while developing card games, works like charm.

Comment: Do you mean I should add the X and Y coordinates to the LinearLayout when dropping or just after motionEvent() call?

Comment: The idea is - upon first touch (ACTION_DOWN) you get the X and Y coordinates from the motionEvent inside your onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) with getX() and getY() methods. You calculate the distance (difference between corresponding coordinates) with the LinearLayout's X and Y, save it to some variables. Then in ACTION_MOVE you use these variables to adjust the movement of the LinearLayout by adding the saved coordinates.